# ssh hangs after authentication

Tags: terminal, macos, ssh, remote-desktop

I used to connect to a remote `Linux` server through `ssh -v remote` from my `osx` client. Now the connection hangs after authentication:

```
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
```

This is happening with both remote servers I have available. I can instead successfully do remote port forwarding (with a not-interacting session) `ssh -fN remote`. I have removed the `.bash*` and `.cshrc` and `.profile` files on the remote servers.

I have checked that the ssh to my remote servers is working correctly on my `Linux` box that I run on `osx` within a virtual box.

I am using the following configuration for ~/.ssh/config

```
ServerAliveInterval 120

Host            *
ForwardX11       yes

Host            remote
HostName        remote.address.uk
HostKeyAlias    remote.address.uk
User            myusername
LocalForward    localhost:5903 remote:5904
LocalForward    localhost:5902 remote:5901
TCPKeepAlive    yes
IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the x forwarding is broken on my `osx`. I have disabled it and now I can connect again